# How to display Apex:pageMessages for Mobile Page

Tags: visualforce, javascript, mobile, html

I am writing a small page for mobile.But I am not sure how to display pageMessages in Mobile.

Original VF page is like this :

```
<apex:page standardController="gii__SalesOrder__c" extensions="SubmitOrderCtlr" id="submitorder" title="Submit Order" action="{!submitOrder}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton value="Go To Order" action="{!gotoOrderDetail}" style="float:right;"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages ></apex:pageMessages>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

So far i have written  something like this.I am stuck on displaying pagemessages though.Any help is appreciated.

```
<apex:page standardController="gii__SalesOrder__c" extensions="SubmitOrderCtlr" id="submitorder" title="Submit Order" action="{!submitOrder}" sidebar="false" tabStyle="gii__SalesOrder__c" standardStylesheets="true">
<head> 
  <title>Submit Order</title>

  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Salesforce1Design, 'responsive.css')}"/>
  <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Salesforce1Design, 'style.css')}"/>

</head>
<body>
    <section id="container">
        <hr/>
        <div id="wrapping" class="clearfix" style="margin-top:1%">
            <div id="responsive-form">
                <apex:form >    
                    <apex:actionFunction name="gotoOrderDetail" action="{!gotoOrderDetail}"/>
                    <script>
                        function orderDetail()
                        {
                            //alert('caling next');
                            gotoOrderDetail();
                            //alert('called');
                        }
                    </script> 
                </apex:form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <section id="buttons" style="float: right;">
                <input type="button" name="Go To order" id="submitbtn" class="submitbtn" value="Go To Order" onclick="orderDetail();"/>           
        </section>
    </section>
</body>


</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:pageMessages>
```

You don't need to do anything special to diaply it on mobile. Just add page message in controller and rerender this component and it will work. And in the page use `standardstylesheet= "true"` so it look will not get mashup.

Or if you want to display it in popup then just get body of this message and display it in popup or any other way or use custom CSS for same.

Comment: do i need to write <apex:pageMessages> or apex:pageMessages???

Comment: `<apex:pageMessages>`